# Vdebug - maximize DebuggerWatch window on load

Tags: vim, xdebug

The vim plugin [vdebug](https://github.com/vim-vdebug/vdebug) opens several splits when it starts the debugger. One of those is `DebuggerWatch` at the top right. I read somewhere I can set an autocmd to listen for that buffer opening and take action. In this case I want to run `:resize 100` to maximize the height. I know how to set an autocmd by filetype or by file glob, but not by a buffer name that is not a file. How do I write an autocmd for this?

I was able to resize on entering the buffer like this:

```
augroup vdebugwatchpanellarger
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufEnter DebuggerWatch resize 999
    autocmd BufEnter DebuggerStack resize 999
augroup END
```

This is helpful because at least if I navigate to one of these buffers it will resize them. But I haven't been able to get it resizing on loading the buffer yet. I tried `BufRead`, `BufNew`, `BufAdd` instead of `BufEnter`. No effect.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin sets the `:help 'syntax'` option of the "DebuggerWatch" window to `debugger_watch` so using the `:help Syntax` event should work:

```
augroup vdebugwatchpanellarger
    autocmd!
    autocmd Syntax debugger_watch resize 999
augroup END
```

Comment: Hm if I change `resize 999` to `echom 'test123'` I get the echo, but for some reason it's not resizing the window.